# how to get all process information in linux kernel module

Tags: process, suspend

I want to store all processes information into image without frozen process, then I can use this image restore process list later. I don't know how to do that, any advice will be appreciated.

If you have to freeze the process, then shorten the freeze time can be.

Thanks.